# Solution to over-damped harmonic spring

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

(A kind soul at [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/74180) suggested I post here as well, sorry if out of bounds.)

I'm trying to programmatically model a damped harmonic spring for use in mobile UI animations (<strike>physics</strike> mathematics isn't my background, please pardon any misconceptions).

Having derived the parameters for the general case equation, I can iteratively calculate values until I reach a suitable threshold, though because this is bound to "simple" trigonometric and $e^{x}$ functions on the CPU, the 4000-some-odd steps can cause about 0.25 seconds lag on slow devices while it calculates. I'd like to speed this up using my platform's super-optimized vector and BLAS/LAPACK variants.

The requirement for doing this is precalculating the number of steps necessary to reach my threshold value.

---

In the underdamped case, where the roots of the characteristic function of the differential equation are non-real, I can use algebraic tricks to get my values:

$$x(t) = c_{1}e^{r_{1}}\cos(i_{1}t) + c_{2}e^{r_{2}}\sin(i_{2}t)$$

(Given $r_{1}$, $i_{1}$, $r_{2}$, and $i_{2}$ are the real and irrational components of my two roots, respectively.)

Knowing that $r_{1} = r_{2}$ and $i_{1} = -i_{2}$, I can simplify to:

$$x(t) = c_{1}e^{r_{1}}\cos(i_{1}t)$$

And get my desired value of $t$ for my threshold $a$:

$$t = \arccos(a / c_{1} / e^{r_{1}}) / i_{1}$$

---

When the roots are real, the equation looks a lot simpler:

$$x(t) = c_{1}e^{r_{1}} + c_{2}e^{r_{2}}$$

However, I don't have my trig functions floating around to help me solve it (even if I did, the irrational components being 0 would cause problems, of course).

Take the concrete example on pages 3-4 of [this document](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-ii-second-order-constant-coefficient-linear-equations/damped-harmonic-oscillators/MIT18_03SCF11_s13_2text.pdf) (my bible during this process), since they at least solve cleanly:

$$x(t) = 1.5e^{-t} - 0.5e^{-3t}$$

I know how I would solve for $t$ to get my for when $x(t) = a$ on paper, by setting $x=e^{t}$, solving, and back substituting, but I don't have that luxury here.

I can make a few assumptions: the roots and constants are all real. I'm always going to be looking for the smallest, first, positive value of $t$. Obviously, the iterative solution is the simplest for this case, but in the end that would involve *more* steps and therefore be slower no matter what my other optimizations would be. How, then, would I go about solving for my threshold value algorithmically in this (supposedly) simplified case?

#### Addendum

The underdamped solution presents an extra requirement. The motion curve will oscillate back and forth a few times across the endpoint. Therefore, "first and lowest" $t$ requirement is not necessarily true. In my current, iterative code, the threshold value is both checked against the distance from the current $x(t)$ to the endpoint, as well as to the distance from the **previous** $x(t)$ as well to allow for a number of oscillations. This might make a more efficient solution nearly impossible.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74180/2451

Comment: In general looking for a close-form solution for $x(t) = c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t} =a$ is not possible. Finding a $t$ numerically by approximation is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the general equation $m \ddot{x} + b \dot{x} + k x = 0$ you can find a solution with the following steps

### Updated Answer

1. From the problem coefficients calculate the characteristic values
   $$ \begin{aligned} \omega_n & = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} 
   \\ \zeta & = \frac{b}{2 \sqrt{k m}} \end{aligned}$$
2. If $\zeta<1$ then calculate solution coefficients from the initial conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=v_0$
   $$ \begin{aligned} \omega & = \omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2} 
   \\ A & = x_0 
   \\ B & = \frac{v_0+x_0 \omega_n \zeta}{\omega}
   \\ r & = \omega_n \zeta  \end{aligned} $$
3. The solution function is
   $$ x(t) = e^{-r t} \left( A \cos(\omega t) + B \sin(\omega t) \right) \tag{1}$$
4. The final time is
   $$ x_{tol} \approx e^{-r t_{final}} \sqrt{A^2+B^2}  \\  t_{final} = \frac{ \ln{ \left( \frac{ \sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{x_{tol}} \right)} } {r} $$
5. If $\zeta>1$ then calculate the solution coefficients from the initial conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=v_0$
   $$ \begin{aligned} \omega & = \omega_n \sqrt{\zeta^2-1}
   \\ C & = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_0 + \frac{v_0 + x_0 \zeta \omega_n}{\omega} \right)
   \\ D & = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_0 - \frac{v_0 + x_0 \zeta \omega_n}{\omega} \right) 
   \\ r_1 & = \left(\zeta - \sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right) \omega_n
   \\ r_2 & = \left(\zeta + \sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right) \omega_n \end{aligned} $$
6. The solution function is
   $$ x(t) = C e^{-r_1 t} + D e^{-r_2 t} \tag{2}$$
7. The final time is
   $$ \begin{aligned} x_{tol} & \approx C e^{-r_1 t_{final}} + 0 
   \\ t_{final} & = \frac{ \ln{\left( \frac{C}{x_{tol}} \right)}}{r_1} \end{aligned} $$ because $r_1<r_2$ and thus decaying slower.
8. For critical damping $\zeta=1$ the solution function is
   $$ x(t) = e^{-\omega_n t} \left(x_0 + (v_0+x_0 \omega_n) t \right) \tag{3}$$
9. The final time is
   $$ \begin{aligned} \ln{\left(x_{tol}\right)} & \approx {\rm Taylor}\left( \ln{\left( (v_0 + x_0 \omega_n) t + x_0 \right)} -\omega_n t, t=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_n},{\rm order}:=1 \right) \\
     X & = \frac{2\pi v_0}{\omega_n} + x_0 (2\pi+1) 
   \\ t_{final} &= \frac{ 2 \pi \left( X \ln \left( \frac{X}{x_{tol}} \right) -X+x_0 \right)}{\omega_n \left( X ( 2\pi -1)+x_0 \right)} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Very cool, that $t_{final}$ solution is nothing short of incredible. However, it doesn't appear to be fitting right - for $b = 25$, $m = 3$, and $k = 200$ for an $x_{0} = 459$, $t_{final}$ is 147s compared to the iterative solution's $t$ value of just 1.12. I appreciate the help massively. Check the question again for an extra condition I added for the underdamped case which might make solving it predictively impossible. Thanks so much again.

Comment: What $x_{tol}$ did you use? When I used $x_{tol}=1$ I get $t_{f} = 1.507$

Comment: Ok I re-worked everything and laid it out in a sequence of steps. Please check again and report on the results.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Simply incredible. The $t_{final}$'s I'm getting are still overestimates, but I can definitely work with that. Off the top of your head, what kind of extra effort would be needed to satisfy the extra case added to the original question, that the absolute value of the velocity also be less than the threshold? If it's too much, your formulae are definitely usable and I'd be ready to mark your response as the answer. Thank you so much, fantastic work.

Comment: Re: the sometimes extreme overestimates. My threshold is really rather small, 0.0001 * the absolute $x_{0}$, and for a case where $k = 1000$ (really high, I know), $m = 3$, and $b = 500$, the old method got me 113 and the new way is 4560. Slight bit more. My final method will use your formulas, but probably use some kind of iteration to bail out earlier in calculation

Comment: @zwaldowski I have made my estimates conservative and thus the overshooting.

Comment: Fair enough. Looks like we're done here!

Answer (score 2):

As your document says, when you have two real roots and the system is overdamped, the one with the longer time constant (inverse of the root) controls how close you are to zero.  So if you are trying to see how long it takes to get close to zero (if $a$ is much smaller than the original displacement) you can ignore the one that falls fastest.  In your example, that is the $e^{-3t}$ term.  You can then solve $a=1.5e^{-t}$ to get $t=-\log \frac a{1.5}$.  As an example, if $a=0.1$, we get $t \approx 2.7$  The other term then contributes $-0.00015$, quite negligible.

If they are very close, you can use Newton's method or fixed point iteration.  Say you were solving $0.1=1.5e^{-t}-0.5e^{-1.01t}$  You would be looking for a root of $f(x)=-0.1+1.5e^{-t}-0.5e^{-1.01t}$, which gives $f'(x)=-1.5e^{-t}+0.505e^{-1.01t}$  For a starting value, ignore the difference of the exponentials and take $x_0=-\log \frac {0.1}{1.5-0.5}\approx2.3$ and $x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac {f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$ which will converge quickly.

Comment: Interesting. Is there some kind of heuristic I should/would be applying for "picking" which of the roots to ignore? Using your earlier half without getting in to the Newton's method approximations yet nets me roughly twice the number of steps (9620 over 4608, .96 over .46 seconds) compared to my old method.

Comment: Additionally, I added an extra condition for the underdamped case to the question which might make solving this predictively impossible. Thanks so much for any and all help.

Comment: As I said, the root to pay attention to is the smaller one-$1$ vs $3$ in your example.  This is because the larger one decays faster.  When they are close, you can use either.  It will change the starting value a little, but you will still get there accurately quickly.